# Should I use an Async task in the description scenario?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-handler

I have a huge ListView backed by a cursor adapter, it has hundreds of thousands of if else conditions with single headers for multiple rows in the bindView, reproducing it here will exceed the limit of characters permitted.

I have certain records in one DB through which this list is populated and I have a different external DB to which I have a connection ready, I want to fetch information from this secondary DB on a button click from the ListView , should I use an Async task or any type of handler here?

The information is very lightweight sometimes only a string of about 20 characters. So far I have not used any, however I don't even feel a performance lag -- What is the best practice here?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, an AsyncTask should be used for something pertaining to its caller.  In other words, if it might outlive its caller, it should probably be a Service or something else.  In your case, yes, an AsyncTask would work fine.

However, if you can pretty much guarantee that the second DB call will return within a few milliseconds, then I wouldn't worry about it.  Your bigger performance bottleneck (even on a separate thread) is probably:

> [cursor adapter with] hundreds of thousands of if else conditions

This makes the maintainer in me go all crazy-eyed.

Comment: There is a note to the maintainer which reads something like this `// 
    // Dear maintainer:
    // 
    // Once you are done trying to 'optimise' this routine,
    // and have realized what a terrible mistake that was,
    // please increment the following counter as a warning
    // to the next guy:
    // 
    // total_hours_wasted_here = 0;
    //`
I dont have much options there as the list is very very finely detailed, each row is different from the other.